# Which has a faster data transfer rate? WIFI (tablet or cell phone, not LTE) or MicroSD (Class 10)?

Tags: memory, speed, tablet, data-transfer

Which of the two methods of dta transfer trasfers data at a faster rate for smartphones and tablets? Standard Wi-Fi, or MicroSD Cards?

I wonder if it would be actually faster to access data on external storage then it would be to have the MicroSD card in my smartphone or tablet.

Currently I have a class 10 32 GB MicroSD card in my cell phone. I am looking to get the new Google Nexus tablet but it does not offer expandable internal storage. I wonder if that's really a detriment; because if Wi-Fi is faster than MicroSD, then it would matter almost none at all that you couldn't expand the storage internally.

If the case is that Wi-Fi is faster, and people caught onto this, then people could save a lot of money on lower memory ipads/iphones/ipods, tablets, and smartphones!

Comment: Do we need to factor in fat-fingering the microSD card, dropping it and scrabbling around the floor looking for the teensy ceramic chip?  'cuz that's gonna effect the results.  Remember that the SD card provides ALWAYS availablily, versus the WIFI's maybe available.  Weigh THOSE concerns too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

802.11n is 600 Mbit/s
SD class 10 is 10 MB/s (80 Mbit/s)

However the former is a theoretical maximum (assuming 4 streams, 4 aerials). 74 mbit/s is more realistic with an ideal signal (no interference, no other nearby Wifi devices).
The latter is sustained minimum *write* speed.

Here's a graph from http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/08/03/28/exploring_time_capsule_theoretical_speed_vs_practical_throughput.html

[image: comparison of data transfer speeds]

Of course, if the data in the phone is on the SD-card in the phone (or in flash memory with equivalent throughput), WiFi can only be slower than directly reading tha card.